# Check if record is present in an other DB with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two websites, I want to check if an author is present on the second website.

$quote is always shown:

**In ENV file:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=poems
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_QUOTES_CONNECTION=quotes
DB_QUOTES_DATABASE=quotes
```

**In config.database.php**

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

    'quotes' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_QUOTES_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
  ]
```

IN authorController.php

```
    public function show($author)
    {
        $author = Author::where('slug', $author)->firstOrFail();
        $poems = $author->poems()->get();

        $quotes = DB::connection('quotes')->table('frasidautore.authors')->select('slug')->where('slug', 'LIKE', '"%{$author->slug}"')->get();

        $author->quotes = ($quotes) ? 'https://www.example.com/authors/' . $author->slug : NULL;

        return view('author', compact(['author', 'poems'])); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->get()` returns a `Collection`, which even if empty, is always "truthy", so using it in a ternary won't work.

Use `isEmpty()` to return `true` or `false` explicitly:

```
$author->quotes = $quotes->isEmpty() ? null : 'https://www.example.com/authors/' . $author->slug';
```

Or, you can simply use `exists()` instead:

```
quotes = DB::connection('quotes')->table('frasidautore.authors')->where('slug', 'LIKE', '"%{$author->slug}"')->exists();

$author->quotes = $quotes ? 'https://www.example.com/authors/' . $author->slug' : null;
```

`exists()` returns `true` or `false` based on the preceding conditions, and can be used in a ternary without worrying about implied "truthyness".

Comment: Perfect! Thanks